# Delete Rows from UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, viewwillappear

Here is the code for my delete, it works fine but you have to open another tab and then click this tab again for the item to be removed. As this is not the normal UITableView you cannot just remove from array and then update table. so could someone please help me refresh the view. Also the snippet below does not work:

```
// Reload the view completely
if ([self isViewLoaded]) {
    self.view=nil;
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

Here is my delete code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
        // Delete song from list & disc \\

        //Remove from arrays
        [self.Writer removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [self.Book removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [self.BookImageId removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        NSString *TempWriter = [self.ArtistNamesArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        NSString *TempBook = [self.SongNamesArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        NSString *TempBookImageId = [self.YoutubeIDSArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];

        TempWriter = [TempWriter substringToIndex:[TempArtistNames length] - 1];
        TempBook = [TempBook substringToIndex:[TempSongNames length] - 1];
        TempBookImageId = [TempBookImageId substringToIndex:[TempYouTube length] - 1];


        //Save Details
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", TempBook] forKey:@"BookName"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", TempWriter] forKey:@"WriterName"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", TempBookImageId] forKey:@"ImageId"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    }


}
```

and my ViewWillAppear code is:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
    // Reload the view completely
    if ([self isViewLoaded]) {
        self.view=nil;
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }

}
```

Thanks for all who will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't appear to be calling the [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `reloadData` method at any point after you've carried out the deletion.

As such, adding...

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

...to the bottom of your `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method should solve the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you either need to call [reloadData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData) or [– deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:).

Answer (score 3):

I have two thoughts on this:

1) You can delete the row in the commitEditingStyle:... method. Here's an example from Apple's "Locations" sample code

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
```

Search the documentation for commitEditingStyle: and you'll find other examples.

2) It looks like you've added code to viewDidLoad to configure the table view. It would be a good idea to remove that code and put it in a separate method such as

```
- (void) updateMyTableView
{
     // Code to reload the table view.
}
```

and then calling it where ever you need it. Calling viewDidLoad directly is not such a good idea because it usually does other things such as '[super viewDidLoad]' which aren't needed to update the table view.

Comment: I had a different issue, where the table would hang (not scroll) shortly after deleting the row/calling `[reloadData]`. Using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` instead fixed that issue!