# Display characteristic of deleting row from TableView when launch application like this image

Tags: iphone, ios, tableview

I want to display the tableview with this image when launch application.

[image]

After we can delete the row  with this image.

[image]

I saw some examples but it use with button (Edit). Could we can do like this ? Please give simple code. Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451027/delete-rows-from-uitableview).

may it helps you. you just need to right one delegate method